# How to prevent page re-sizing for mobile browsers

Tags: categories, customization, css

I want to prevent my page resizing for mobile browsers, How can I achieve this?
My `style.css` is added below.

```
*/

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* DEFAULTS */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* reset */
@import "css/reset.css";
body{ background:url(http://i.imgur.com/.jpg); font:12px/19px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; color:#333; }

/* hyperlinks */
a, a:visited, a:active{ color:#222; text-decoration:none; }
a:hover{ color:#369; text-decoration:underline; }

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* CONTAINERS */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#wrapper{ width:960px; margin:15px auto; }
#column1{ float:left; width:647px; }
.wrap{ width:960px; margin:0px auto; }



/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* TOP */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#top{ background:#222 url(images/bg-top.jpg) repeat-x top center; height:29px; color:#fff; font-size:11px; line-height:30px; border-top:1px solid #333; }
#top .subscribe{ padding:9px 10px 0px 0px; }

/* top navigation */
.topnav{ z-index:99; margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style:none; line-height:1; }
.topnav a{ position:relative; color:#fff; display:block; z-index:100; text-decoration:none; }
.topnav li{ float:left; width:auto; }
.topnav li a{ background:url(images/icon-top-seperator.gif) no-repeat 0px 10px; padding:7px 11px; font-size:18px; line-height:15px; text-decoration:none; }
.topnav li a:hover, .topnav li a:active, .topnav li.current-cat, .topnav li.current-cat-parent{ color:#fff; text-decoration:underline; }
.topnav li a:visited{ color:#fff; }
.topnav li.first a{ background:none; padding-left:0px !important; }
.topnav li.last a{ padding-right:0px !important; }
.topnav li a.sf-with-ul{  }
.topnav li ul{ background:#fff; position:absolute; left:-999em; width:158px; border:1px solid #dbdbdb; border-width:1px 1px 0px; z-index:999; }
.topnav li ul li{ border-top:1px solid #fff; border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdb; }
.topnav li ul li a, .topnav li ul li a:visited{ background:#f5f5f5; width:136px; padding:5px 11px; color:#222; font-size:11px; font-weight:normal; }
.topnav li ul li a.sf-with-ul{ padding:5px 11px; }
.topnav li ul li a:hover{ background:#eaeaea; color:#222; }
.topnav li ul ul{ margin:-27px 0px 0px 158px; }
.topnav li ul ul li a{  }
.topnav li ul li ul li a{  }
.topnav li:hover, .topnav li.hover{ position:static; }
.topnav li:hover ul ul, .topnav li.sfhover ul ul,
.topnav li:hover ul ul ul, .topnav li.sfhover ul ul ul,
.topnav li:hover ul ul ul ul, .topnav li.sfhover ul ul ul ul{ left:-999em; }
.topnav li:hover ul, .topnav li.sfhover ul,
.topnav li li:hover ul, .topnav li li.sfhover ul,
.topnav li li li:hover ul, .topnav li li li.sfhover ul,
.topnav li li li li:hover ul, .topnav li li li li.sfhover ul{ left:auto; }

/* topnav indicator */
.topnav .sf-sub-indicator{ display:none; }
.topnav li ul .sf-sub-indicator{ background:url(images/icon-arrow-right.png) no-repeat; position:absolute; display:block; right:0.4em; top:0.9em; width:10px; height:10px; text-indent:-999em; overflow:hidden; }

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* HEADER */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header{ background:#333 url(images/bg-header.png) no-repeat top center; height:100px; line-height:100px; }

/* text logo */
#logo{ width:600px; height:99px; max-height:99px; }
#logo h1{ padding:19px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:38px; font-weight:bold; line-height:38px; letter-spacing:-2px; }
#logo h1 a, #logo h1 a:hover, #logo h1 a:visited{ color:#fff; text-decoration:none; }
#logo p{ padding:12px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:12px; font-style:italic; color:#f0f0f0; line-height:12px; }

/* image logo */
#logo img{ margin:17px 0px 0px -5px; cursor:pointer; }

/* search form */
#search{ float:right; width:236px; height:25px; margin:30px 0px 0px 0px; }
#search input{ float:left; background:url(images/bg-search.png) repeat-x top; width:220px; padding:8px 8px 7px 8px; font-family:Georgia, Times New Roman; font-size:12px; font-style:italic; color:#666; line-height:12px; border:1px solid #ccc; }
#search input.btn{ background:none; border:none; margin:9px 0px 0px -27px; padding:0px; width:auto; }

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* CATEGORY MENU */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#cat-menu{ background:url(images/bg-cat-menu.jpg) repeat-x bottom center; height:47px; border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }

/* category navigation */
.nav{ z-index:99; float:left; margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style:none; line-height:1; height:47px; border-left:1px solid #ddd; border-right:1px solid #fff; }
.nav a{ position:relative; color:#333; display:block; z-index:100; text-decoration:none; }
.nav li{ float:left; width:auto; border-left:1px solid #fff; border-right:1px solid #ddd; }
.nav li a{ font:bold 12px/15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:16px 17px; text-decoration:none; }
.nav li a:hover, .nav li a:active, .nav li.current-cat, .nav li.current-cat-parent{ background:#f5f5f5; color:#369; }
.nav li a.sf-with-ul{  }
.nav li ul{ background:#fff; position:absolute; left:-999em; width:182px; margin:0px 0px 0px -2px; border:1px solid #dbdbdb; border-width:1px 1px 0px; z-index:999; }
.nav li ul li{ border-top:1px solid #fff; border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdb; border-right:none; }
.nav li ul li a{ background:#f5f5f5; width:147px; padding:7px 17px; color:#333; font-size:12px; font-weight:normal; }
.nav li ul li a.sf-with-ul{ padding:7px 17px; }
.nav li ul li a:hover{ background:#ebebeb; text-decoration:underline; }
.nav li ul ul{ margin:-31px 0px 0px 181px; }
.nav li ul ul li a{  }
.nav li ul li ul li a{  }
.nav li:hover,.nav li.hover{ position:static; }
.nav li:hover ul ul, .nav li.sfhover ul ul,
.nav li:hover ul ul ul, .nav li.sfhover ul ul ul,
.nav li:hover ul ul ul ul, .nav li.sfhover ul ul ul ul{ left:-999em; }
.nav li:hover ul, .nav li.sfhover ul,
.nav li li:hover ul, .nav li li.sfhover ul,
.nav li li li:hover ul, .nav li li li.sfhover ul,
.nav li li li li:hover ul, .nav li li li li.sfhover ul{ left:auto; }

/* category navigation indicator */
.nav .sf-sub-indicator{ display:none; }
.nav li ul .sf-sub-indicator{ background:url(images/icon-arrow-right.png) no-repeat; position:absolute; display:block; right:0.4em; top:0.9em; width:10px; height:10px; text-indent:-999em; overflow:hidden; }

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* POST BOXES */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.post{ width:645px; margin:0px 0px 15px 0px; border:1px solid #dfdfdf; }
.postbox{ background:#fff url(images/bg-box.png) repeat-x top center; width:605px; padding:20px; border-bottom:1px solid #dfdfdf; }
.postbox h2{ margin:0px 0px 5px 0px; font-size:26px; font-weight:bold; line-height:30px; letter-spacing:-1px; }
.postbox h2 a, .postbox h2 a:visited{ color:#222; text-decoration:none; }
.postbox h2 a:hover{ color:#000; }
.post-date{ margin:10px 0px; color:#fff; }
.post-date a, .post-date a:visited{ color:#369; border-bottom:1px dotted #369; }
.post-date a:hover{ border-bottom:none; text-decoration:none; }
.post-date em{ background:none; font:12px/16px Georgia; color:#777; }
.post-exerpt{  }
.post-thumb{ float:left; margin:0px 20px 5px 0px; }
.post-thumb img{ background:#fff; padding:4px; border:1px solid #e6e6e6; }
.post-bottom{ background:#fff url(images/bg-cat-menu.jpg) repeat-x top center; height:43px; padding:0px 20px; }
.filedin{ float:left; background:url(images/icon-file.png) no-repeat 0px -1px; width:545px; margin:14px 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px 0px 0px 19px; color:#555; }
.filedin a, .filedin a:visited{ color:#555; border-bottom:1px dotted #999; }
.filedin a:hover{ color:#369; text-decoration:none; border-bottom:none; }
.small-comment-cloud{ float:right; background:url(images/bg-small-comment-cloud.png); width:32px; height:32px; margin:5px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; line-height:30px; text-align:center; }
.small-comment-cloud a{ color:#369; text-shadow:#fff 0px 1px 0px; }

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* CONTENT */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#fullcontent{ background:#fff url(images/bg-box.png) repeat-x top center; width:920px; padding:25px 20px; border:1px solid #dfdfdf; }
#content{ float:left; background:#fff url(images/bg-box.png) repeat-x top center; width:605px; padding:25px 20px; border:1px solid #dfdfdf; }

/* browsing */
#browsing{ background:#fff url(images/bg-box.png) repeat-x top left; width:605px; height:20px; margin:0px 0px 15px 0px; padding:15px 20px; line-height:20px; border:1px solid #dfdfdf; }
#browsing h1{ float:left; font:18px/18px Arial; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:-1px; }
#browsing .catfeed{ float:right; background:url(images/icon-cat-rss.png) no-repeat right 3px; padding:0px 17px 0px 0px; }
#browsing .catfeed a:hover{ text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted #369; }

/* page title*/
.pagetitle{ padding:0px 0px 10px 0px; font:bold 26px/28px Arial; letter-spacing:-1px; }
.pagetitle a, .pagetitle a:hover{ color:#222 !important; text-decoration:none; }

/* post header & title */
.post-header{ float:left; width:545px; }
.post-title{ margin:0px 0px 10px 0px; font-size:26px; font-weight:bold; line-height:30px; letter-spacing:-1px; }
.post-title a, .post-title a:visited{ color:#222; }

/* comment cloud */
.comment-cloud{ float:right; background:url(images/bg-comment-cloud.png); width:42px; height:42px; font:bold 16px/35px Arial; text-align:center; }
.comment-cloud a{ color:#369; text-shadow:#fff 0px 1px 0px; }

/* entry */
.entry{ padding:10px 0px 15px 0px; }
.entry p{ padding-bottom:10px; }
.entry strong{ font-weight:bold; }
.entry em{ font-style:italic; font-weight:normal; }
.entry strong em, .entry em strong{ font-style:italic; font-weight:bold; }
.entry h1{ font:24px/26px Arial; font-weight:bold; padding:0px 0px 10px 0px; letter-spacing:-1px; }
.entry h2{ font:22px/24px Arial; font-weight:bold; padding:0px 0px 10px 0px; letter-spacing:-1px; }
.entry h3{ font:20px/22px Arial; font-weight:bold; padding:0px 0px 10px 0px; }
.entry h4{ font:17px/19px Arial; font-weight:bold; padding:0px 0px 10px 0px; }
.entry h5{ font:15px/17px Arial; font-weight:bold; padding:0px 0px 10px 0px; }
.entry h6{ font:13px/16px Arial; font-weight:bold; padding:0px 0px 10px 0px; }
.entry a, .entry a:visited{ color:#369; }
.entry a:hover{ color:#369; text-decoration:underline; }
.entry a img{ border:none; }
.entry ul{ margin:0px 0px 0px 7px; padding-bottom:10px; list-style:none; }
.entry ol{ margin:0px 0px 10px 25px; list-style-type:decimal; }
.entry ol ol{ list-style:upper-alpha; }
.entry ol ol ol{ list-style:lower-roman; }
.entry ol ol ol ol{ list-style:lower-alpha; }
.entry ul ul, .entry ol ol, .entry ul ol, .entry ol ul{ margin-bottom:0px; }
.entry ul li{ background:url(images/icon-bullet.png) no-repeat 0px 5px; padding:3px 0px 3px 19px; font-size:12px; line-height:19px; }
.entry ol li{ padding:3px 0px 3px 0px; font-size:12px; line-height:19px; }
.entry li a:link, .entry li a:visited{ color:#222; }
.entry li a:hover{ color:#369; }
.entry li ul{ margin:0px; padding:0px; }
.entry del{ text-decoration:line-through; color:#aaa; }
.entry ins{ text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; }
.entry blockquote{ margin:20px 0px; padding:15px 15px 1px 15px; background:#f5f5f5; border:1px solid #eee; border-width:1px 0px; font-family:Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif; }
.entry blockquote p, blockquote a, blockquote{ color:#666; font-style:italic; font-size:1em; }
.entry dfn{ font-weight:bold; }
.entry pre, .entry code, .entry tt{ margin:1.5em 0px; white-space:pre; display:block; }
.entry pre, .entry code, .entry tt{ font:12px 'andale mono', 'monotype.com', 'lucida console', monospace; line-height:20px; background:#f5f5f5; overflow:auto; padding:1em; color:#666; }
.entry hr{ background:#e6e6e6; color:#e6e6e6; clear:both; width:100%; height:1px; margin:15px 0px; border:none; }
.entry input, .entry textarea{ font-size:1em; padding:3px; }

/* post images */
img.centered{ display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom:10px; padding:0px; }
img.alignnone{ padding:0px; margin:0px 0px 10px 0px; display:inline; }
img.alignright{ padding:0px; margin:0px 0px 10px 10px; display:inline; }
img.alignleft{ padding:0px; margin:0px 10px 10px 0px; display:inline; }
.aligncenter{ display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom:10px; }
.alignright{ float:right; margin:0px 0px 10px 10px; }
.alignleft{ float:left; margin:0px 10px 10px 0px; }
.wp-caption{ background:#F7F7F7; text-align:center; padding:4px 0px 5px 0px; border:1px solid #e6e6e6; }
.wp-caption img{ margin:0px 0px 5px 0px; padding:0px; border:0px; }
.wp-caption p.wp-caption-text{ margin:0px; padding:0px; font-size:11px; font-weight:normal; line-height:12px; }

/* tags */
.tags{ background:#fff url(images/icon-tag.png) no-repeat 0px 1px; margin:5px 0px 0px 0px; padding:0px 0px 0px 21px; color:#222; }
.tags a, .tags a:visited{ color:#222; text-decoration:none; }
.tags a:hover{ color:#369; text-decoration:underline; }

/* post navigation */
.postnavi{ padding:7px 0px 10px 0px; border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6; }
.postnavi a:hover{ text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted #369; }
.postnavi p{ font-family:Georgia, Times New Roman; font-style:italic; font-size:11px; color:#777; clear:both; text-transform:uppercase; }
.postnavi .left{ width:295px; text-align:left; }
.postnavi .right{ width:295px; text-align:right; }

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* SIDEBAR */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#sidebar{ float:right; width:300px; }

/* ad blocks */
.adbox{ background:url(images/bg-box.png) repeat-x; padding:18px 18px 3px 18px; }
.ad300x300{ width:300px; height:300px; margin:0px 0px 15px 0px; }

/* subscribe widget */
#subscribe{ background:#FEFEFE url(images/bg-box.png) repeat-x; width:290px; margin:0px 0px 15px 0px; padding:8px 5px; border:1px solid #ddd; font-size:90%; }
.subscribe_icons{ width:286px; margin:0px auto; }
.subscribe_icons li{ display:inline; float:left; margin:0px 2px 5px 2px; width:52px; text-align:center; font-size:11px; }
.subscribe_icons a{ display:block; padding:40px 0px 2px; -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-out; -moz-transition:all .2s ease-out; color:#444 !important; }
.subscribe_icons a:hover{ color:#369 !important; text-decoration:none; -moz-box-shadow:0px 2px 4px hsla(0,0%,0%,.35); -webkit-box-shadow:0px 2px 4px hsla(0,0%,0%,.35); }
.subscribe_icons .subscribe_buzz a{ background:url(images/icon-buzz.png) center top no-repeat; }
.subscribe_icons .subscribe_twitter a{ background:url(images/icon-twitter.png) center top no-repeat; }
.subscribe_icons .subscribe_facebook a{ background:url(images/icon-facebook.png) center top no-repeat; }
.subscribe_icons .subscribe_rss a{ background:url(images/icon-rss.png) center top no-repeat; }
.subscribe_icons .subscribe_email a{ background:url(images/icon-email.png) center top no-repeat; }

/* tabber */
#tabber{ background:#FEFEFE url(images/bg-box.png) repeat-x; height:auto; display:block; }
#tabber .inside{ padding:0px 15px 0px 15px; }
#tabber ul.tabs{ height:53px; background:url(images/bg-widget-title.png) repeat-x center top; padding:0px 5px; }
#tabber ul.tabs li{ background:none; float:left; display:inline; font-size:11px; color:#fff; margin:0px 1px 0px 0px; padding:0px 0px 0px 5px; cursor:pointer; border-bottom:none; }
#tabber ul.tabs li a.selected, #tabber ul.tabs li a:hover{ color:#369; text-decoration:none; background:url(images/bg-tabs-selected.png) no-repeat center 41px; border-bottom:none; }
#tabber ul.tabs li a{ color:#444; line-height:42px; display:block; float:left; padding:0px 7px 10px; text-transform:uppercase; }
#tabber #tag-cloud, #tabber .inside li{ padding:10px 0px; }
#tabber .inside li{ background:none; border-bottom:1px solid #ededed; }
#tabber .inside li a{ color:#333; line-height:19px; }
#tabber .inside a:hover{ color:#369; }
#tabber .inside li div.info{ display:table; top:0px !important; margin:0px !important; padding:0px !important; }
#tabber .inside li span.meta{ display:block; font:italic 11px/20px Georgia, Times New Roman; color:#999; }
#tabber .inside li span.meta a{ color:#999; }
#tabber .inside li span.meta a:hover{ color:#369; text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted #369; }
#tabber .inside li img.avatar, #tabber .inside li img.thumb{ border:1px solid #f0f0f0; padding:2px; background:#fff; float:left; margin:0px 8px 0px 0px; }

/* widgets */
.widget{ background:#fff; width:300px; margin:0px 0px 15px 0px; border:1px solid #dfdfdf; }
.widget h3{ background:url(images/bg-widget-title.png) repeat-x; height:43px; padding:0px 15px; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; color:#444; line-height:42px; letter-spacing:-1px; }
.widget p{ padding-bottom:5px; }
.widget ul{ clear:both; margin:0px; }
.widget ul li{ background:url(images/icon-arrow.png) no-repeat 0px 10px; padding:8px 0px 8px 19px; border-bottom:1px solid #ededed; }
.widget ul li a{ padding:0px; text-decoration:none; color:#333; }
.widget ul li a:hover{ color:#369; text-decoration:underline; }
.widget ul ul{ margin:0px; padding:0px; border-top:none; }
.widget ul ul li{ border:none; }
.widgetbox{ background:url(images/bg-box.png) repeat-x; padding:10px 15px 15px 15px; }
.textwidget{ padding-top:5px; }

/* calendar */
#wp-calendar{ width:100%; }
#wp-calendar, #wp-calendar th, #wp-calendar caption{ text-align:center; }
#wp-calendar th{ background:#f5f5f5; padding:3px; border:1px solid #f0f0f0; }
#wp-calendar td{ padding:5px 2px; border:1px solid #f0f0f0; }
#wp-calendar caption{ background:transparent; font-weight:bold; padding:3px 0px 7px 0px; color:#333; }
#wp-calendar #today{ background:#f5f5f5; font-weight:bold; }

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* COMMENTS */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#respond{ margin:15px 0px 0px 0px; }
#respond p{ color:#777; margin:0px; }
.comments-box{ padding:30px 0px 0px 0px; border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6; }
.comments-box h3{ font-size:14px; letter-spacing:-1px; }
.cancel-comment-reply{ padding:5px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:11px; }
.text{ border:1px solid #e6e6e6; padding:2px; color:#777; width:200px; }

/* comment framework */
#pings{ margin-bottom:40px; }
ul.children{ margin-left:0px; }
ol.commentlist{ margin:15px 0px 0px 0px; }
cite.fn{ font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; font-style:normal; letter-spacing:-0.05em; display:block; padding-top:9px; }
cite.fn a, cite.fn a:hover{ color:#333; text-decoration:none; }
span.says{ display:none; }
.commentlist li{ margin:-1px 0px 0px 0px; padding:15px; list-style:none; border-top:1px solid #e9e9e9; border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9; }
.commentlist li.depth-2{ background:#ffffff; border-top:1px solid #e9e9e9; border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9; margin-left:15px; }
.commentlist li.depth-3{ background:#fafafa; border-top:1px solid #e9e9e9; border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9; margin-left:15px; }
.commentlist li.depth-4{ background:#ffffff; border-top:1px solid #e9e9e9; border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9; margin-left:15px; }
.commentlist li.depth-5{ background:#fafafa; border-top:1px solid #e9e9e9; border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9; margin-left:15px; }
.commentlist code{ background:#e6e6e6; padding:5px; }
.commentlist .moderation{ margin-top:10px; color:#660000; }
.commentlist .thread-even{ background:#fafafa; }
.commentlist .children{ margin-top:15px; }
.commentlist p{ clear:both; }
.comment-author{ margin-bottom:5px; }
.avatar{ margin-right:10px; float:left; padding:2px; border:1px solid #e6e6e6; background:#fff; }
.reply{ margin:15px 0px 0px 0px; }
.reply a, .reply a:visited{ color:#fff; text-align:center; font-size:10px; padding:0px 6px 1px !important; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none !important; }
.comment-meta{ float:left; margin-bottom:15px; }
.comment-meta a{ color:#666; }
.comment-date a, .comment-date a:visited{ color:#888; font-size:1.1em; }

/* comment form */
#commentform{ margin:10px 0 0 0; }
#commentform input.txt, #commentform textarea{ font:14px/14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-color:#ccc #efefef #efefef #ccc; border-width:1px; border-style:solid; }
#commentform input.txt{ color:#666; background:#fcfcfc; width:170px; margin:0 5px 10px 0; padding:5px 7px; }
#commentform textarea{ color:#666; background:#fcfcfc; width:95% !important; padding:5px 7px; }
#commentform #submit{ margin:15px 0 0 0; }

/* subbmit & reply button */
.button, .button:visited, .reply a{ display:inline-block; position:relative; background:url(images/alert-overlay.png); padding:5px 8px 6px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#fff !important; text-decoration:none; border:none; cursor:pointer; }
.button, .button:visited, .reply a{ background-color:#666; }
.button:hover, .reply a:hover{ color:#fff  !important; text-decoration:none; }
.button:active, .reply a:active{ top:0px; }
.button, .button:visited{ font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; line-height:1; }
.button, .button:visited{ text-shadow:0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); }
.button, .button:visited, .reply a{ text-shadow:0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.25); border-bottom-color:rgba(0,0,0,.35); border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); }
.button:hover, .reply a:hover{ opacity:0.9; }

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* PAGINATION */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* default pagination */
.pagination{ margin:15px 0px 0px 0px; padding:5px 0px; font-size:12px; font-style:italic; line-height:18px; }
.pagination a{ display:block; background:#fff; margin:0px; padding:4px 8px; color:#369; text-shadow:#fff 0px 1px 0px; border:1px solid #dfdfdf; }
.pagination a:hover{ background:#ddd; border:1px solid #ccc; }
.pagination .left a{ background-image:url(images/icon-arrow-left.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:8px center; padding-left:20px; }
.pagination .right a{ background-image:url(images/icon-arrow-right.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:95% center; padding-right:20px; }

/* wp-pagenavi */
.pagination .wp-pagenavi{ text-align:right; }
.pagination .wp-pagenavi a:link, .pagination .wp-pagenavi a:visited{ display:inline; background:#fff; color:#369; margin:0px 0px 0px 3px; padding:4px 8px; border:1px solid #ccc; text-decoration:none; }
.pagination .wp-pagenavi .on, .pagination .wp-pagenavi .current, .pagination .wp-pagenavi a:hover{ background:#efefef; margin:0px 0px 0px 3px; padding:4px 8px; font-weight:normal; color:#369; border:1px solid #ccc; }
.pagination .wp-pagenavi .extend, .pagination .wp-pagenavi span.pages{ background:#fff; padding:4px 8px; color:#333; text-shadow:#fff 0px 1px 0px; border:1px solid #ccc; }

/* comments navigation */
.navigation{ padding:20px 0px 0px 0px; font-style:italic; }

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* FOOTER */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#footer{ background:#e6e6e6 url(images/bevel-footer.png) repeat-x top center; margin:30px 0px 0px 0px; padding:25px 0px 10px 0px; }

/* footer widgets */
#footer1{ float:left; width:229px; }
#footer2{ float:left; width:229px; margin:0px 0px 0px 15px; }
#footer3{ float:left; width:229px; margin:0px 0px 0px 15px; }
#footer4{ float:right; width:228px; }
.footerwidget{ background:#fff; margin:0px 0px 15px 0px; box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #bbb; -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #bbb; -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #bbb; }
.footerwidget h3{ background:url(images/bg-cat-menu.jpg) repeat-x top center; height:43px; padding:0px 15px; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; color:#333; line-height:44px; letter-spacing:-1px; border-bottom:1px solid #dfdfdf; }
.footerwidget ul li{ background:url(images/icon-bullet.png) no-repeat 0px 10px; padding:8px 0px 8px 19px; border-bottom:1px solid #ededed; }

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* BOTTOM */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#bottom{ background:#bbb url(images/bevel-bottom.png) repeat-x top center; padding:10px 0px; font-family:georgia; font-style:italic; color:#333; }
#bottom a{ color:#333; }
#bottom a:hover{ color:#222; text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted #333; }
```

Comment: But there are no `media-queries` used?

Comment: Actually he will have to remove `viewport meta tag` from header.

Comment: Please note that purely CSS questions are considered [not in scope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and are better asked at [so].

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you want. But I assume you want the desktop view in your mobile browser instead of responsive layout.

You can use viewport to achieve this. 
Please check this tutorial:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972